# Как пронумеровать каждую страницу OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

Здравствуйте задаюсь вопросом как пронумеровать страницы ворде(то есть добавить в колонтитул номера страниц) с помощью OpenXML или другой библиотеки это не важно.

Знаю как добавлять колонтитул [тут](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b05050d-037d-48ba-bdba-a1092d71142f/add-different-header-and-footer-on-pages-office-openxml-sdk-20?forum=oxmlsdk),но не знаю на каждую страницу то есть ст.1 записать в колонтитул 1,ст.2 записать в колонтитул 2 и тд...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ на мой вопрос-https://github.com/GlenConway/DocXPlus.

DocX Plus — это уровень абстракции над компонентами Word Processor Open XML SDK, предоставляющий более интуитивно понятную объектную модель для создания документов обработки текстов.